# Intrinsic gas too low and exceeds block limit

Tags: javascript, transactions, bitcoin, ethereum

I am trying to create and broadcast a raw transaction on the ethereum testnet network as this would allow for a more lightweight application that can run without a full node. I am trying to broadcast a raw transaction but it is not working because of the issues specified in the title. I have altered the gas price and limit but it makes the same issues.

```
function createRawTransacton(){
var privateKey = new Buffer('d3780dd620ef80b3918dfcdb9105f76147fc55a3775ff71805ccec09a89063ed', 'hex')
var rawTx = {
   nonce: 'CX350',
   gasPrice: 'C350',
   gasLimit: '0x09184e72a000',
   to: '0xc5622be5861b7200cbace14e28b98c4ab77bd9b4',
   value: 'CX350',
   data: '0x19dacbf83c5de6658e14cbf7bcae5c15eca2eedecf1c66fbca928e4d351bea0f'
}
var tx = new Tx(rawTx)
tx.sign(privateKey)
var serializedTx = tx.serialize()
console.log(serializedTx.toString('hex'))
broadCastTx(serializedTx.toString('hex'))
}
```

If anyone also has information on executing contract functions with this raw transaction than that would also be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the public testnet (morden), the default block gas limit is  4,712,388 (4.7 million).

Your raw transaction is set to limit:

```
gasLimit: '0x09184e72a000',
```

Which is `10^13` (10 trillion). That's why you get 'Exceeds block gas limit'. Try to set your gas limit to 4 million:

```
gasLimit: '0x3d0900',
```

See also [this question on Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1832/87).